# How to transfer inputted text, into output field

Tags: javascript, html

Im not sure what to search on google but here is what Im trying to do..

Currently this is my HTML code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Product Code weight convertor</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="styling.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Product Code" class="pcode">
    <button class="btn=find"><i class="x"></i>Find</button>
    <div class="res" id="res1">Result1</div>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Where it says `result1` id like that to change to whatever has been inputted in the text field provided after button been clicked on.

Lets say...
I have enetered `123` into the text field. Click `Find`, the `result1` now changes to `123`.

Im not sure where to start with this one, have already looked into google for readings, but couldn't find anything useful.

Comment: Post your JavaScript too please

Comment: Then you have posted to SO too early. Remember that this is not a general help forum, but a place to ask questions about code you're writing, or working with. Take the [tour], and read through [how to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask): first you are on the hook to search, and research, and in this case learning to write javascript is very much a "research" task. There are a lot of good tutorials out there (find some that explicitly talk about using modern JS, "ES6", "ES2018", etc. so you don't end up getting taught how to use JS the way we used it quite literally 20 years ago).

Comment: This basically sounds like you want us to teach you JavaScript from scratch? (And HTML/CSS too, obviously, unless it's a typo that you're using an equal sign in the css class name of your button...)

Comment: Where would you reccomend me to read to achieve this task?

Comment: I learn from answers.. everyones got different learning methods

Comment: No one would help you for these kind of questions. First you should learn HTML and JavaScript basics. Then, these are pretty easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a `click` event listener to `button` element. When button is clicked, get the value from the input field and display it in the result `div` element

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('.btn-find');
const inputField = document.querySelector('.pcode');
const result = document.querySelector('.res');

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (inputField.value !== '') {
     result.textContent = inputField.value;
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Product Code weight convertor</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="styling.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Product Code" class="pcode">
    <button class="btn-find"><i class="x"></i>Find</button>
    <div class="res" id="res1">Result1</div>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Yousaf for your positive answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add a class to your input:

```
<input id="myText" type="text" placeholder="Product Code" class="pcode">
```

and some JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("res1").innerHTML = document.getElementById("myText").value;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Frank, thanks for your answer.. where did you learn this? If you wouldn't mind sharing

Comment: Here's an about how to get the value:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_value.asp

And here's one to put it somewhere:
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_html.asp

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

In-case you use jquery, you can do like this.

```
<input type="text" class="search__input">
<button>click</button>
```

---

```
$("button").click(event => {
  let result = $(".search__input").val();
  console.log(result);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this, say the find button id is id="find"

```
$("#find").click(function(){ 
var inputdata = $(".pcode").val();
document.getElementById("res1").innerHTML = inputdata;
});
```

you can try this code. It will work.